# How to remove a query parameter from URL without refresh the router in Ember js

Tags: url, ember.js, web-deployment, router, query-string

I have a website built from Ember.js. A user can access a page through URL *http://..../view?showTitle=true*. However I don't want to explicitly expose the parameter *showTitle=true* to the user (meaning user will only see *http://..../view*). This URL is automatically generated and serves as a redirect destination URL. So, I have to remove it manually somewhere before the page load. But I still need this value of this query parameter to query data. Is there a way to achieve that (A example would be great)? What about do it without refreshing the router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, an example of your scenario would be greater :)

There are some other ways to store data while transitioning to a route. Such as: storing the params in `transition` object or storing the value in a service. Create a redirection route, use `beforeModel` hook to grab the value from query params then do a redirection to the real route.

A working example is: [ember-twiddle-1](https://ember-twiddle.com/defd5ece3678b5b1ae1f734f8af2a7e8/59073981b39df45a28999fb9f9cfc707b156ca50)

By the way, even if you don't describe your `queryParams`in your routes, you can access them via `transition.queryParams`. This seems a bit hacky. But it works: [ember-twiddle-2](https://ember-twiddle.com/286016ab918a94c6c070afe321d8397c?openFiles=routes.my-route.js%2C) (Note: It doesn't work in the same route.)

**Updated:**

At the `setupController` hook you can override the controller parameters. So you can remove the parameters from the url. [ember-twiddle-3](https://ember-twiddle.com/d9ba42ced2de2cc664bd66b77ffd5e68?openFiles=routes.my-route.js%2C&route=%2Fmy-route)

Comment: Thanks for the example. `this.transitionTo({queryParams: {showTitle: undefined}});`  works for transiting to the same model. Is there a way to achieve so without making any transition call?

Comment: Yes. By overriding the `setupController` hook. I've just updated my answer and added the third twiddle.

Comment: Yeah, this is great! It seems to work well on twiddle. But when I run it locally it only work when I click the links in the page. Manually open *http://localhost:4200/my-route?showTitle=false* won't update the link to remove the parameter. In my case, this URL is composed from back end. So we can take it as the user input.

Comment: @Hengstar Then use none of the alternatives above, only use `window.history.replaceState({},'my-route','my-route');` in your `model` hook of `my-route` route. (But caution: older browsers may behave different. [Link](http://caniuse.com/#search=replaceState)) I couldn't test it in twiddle, can you inform me about the result?

Comment: It worked locally! I also found an example of using replaceState by adding `replace: true` attribute. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/emberjs/route_url_rplc.htm But I didn't get it worked as I expected. Anyway, I think `window.history.replaceState` is enough for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome! But be careful about side-effects of this: legacy browsers may not support this (need to wrap with try-catch). In production environment you may need to append different parameters (such as rootURL). Back button may redirect the page without `showTitle` parameter...